# The uncertainty principle - Why does it imply that we can't localise?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

The uncertainty principle states that if you have a signal which is very concentrated in time, then its Fourier transform will be rather outspread and vice versa. However, I don't really understand how this implies that in general we can't find a function that gives us the frequency spectrum for a particular point in time.

I don't even know what exactly is meant with determining the frequency spectrum at a specific point in time. If I wanted to localise
the frequency better (e.g. at zero), I would multiply by a corresponding indicator function and consider the fourier transform, i.e.  consider
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_{ \mathbb{R}} f( x) {1}_{ [ - \epsilon , \epsilon ] }  ( x)  e^{ -2\pi i\xi x}\, dx 
.\end{aligned}
$$
However, with this interpretation the frequency spectrum at $ x = 0$ doesn't really make sense, since for $ \epsilon  \to 0$ this integral will vanish. Can someone
clarify this a bit?

Comment: Is the conclusion you’re trying to understand from a book?

Comment: Multiply with a Dirac delta "function" instead. Then the integral won't vanish. But look at the spectrum; is it localized or very spread out?

Comment: @md2perpe so that the spectrum is very spread out means we can't really point out a "single" frequency that is "most contained" in our signal?

Comment: Surely, to measure a frequency, some kind of oscillation needs to happen, and for that to happen, you need a certain interval of time to pass. Measuring an oscillation at one time point makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

There *is* a "best possible distribution function" for the simultaneous frequency-time domain: it's called the Wigner distribution function (WDF) for the signal.

However, you can *never* have a signal that *is* perfectly localized in both frequency and time, i.e. its WDF is a delta spike in two dimensions. Think about it counterfactually: suppose we had a signal pulse, instant, that occurred both *exactly* at time 5 seconds and with a frequency *exactly* at 50 Hertz. Then we had *another* instant signal, *also* occurring at time 5 seconds, with a frequency *exactly* 500 Hertz.

Both are an instant, point-sized signal i.e. a delta spike. The only thing that *can* differ between them, then, is their generalized amplitude. How, then, can the 50 vs. 500 Hz *frequency* difference be meaningful? So there must be a limit on the simultaneous localization, and that is on the order of one square unit in the FT space.

But that doesn't mean you can't *come up with* the distribution. It just means you can't make that distribution *to be* of point support for any possible signal.